# Django follow feature with m2m

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm, many-to-many

I tried to solve the problem and got stuck. The problem is that I have a post that I can follow. My problem is that I don't know how to add a tracking button. Should this be done by url, with a view? Or should it be rather as a method in the model?

My problem is also whether it is properly written in terms of models - using the intermediate model Follower?

Here is Post model and I would like to add followers here. I mean, everybody who is interested, can follow this post.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1024)
    followers = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, through='Follower', blank=True)
    is_visible = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('posts:post_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def number_of_followers(self):
        return self.followers.count()
```

Here is my manager for follower model:

```
class FollowerManager(models.Manager):
    use_for_related_fields = True

    def follow(self, user, pk):
        post_object = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
        if user.is_authenticated():
            if user in post_object.followers.all():
                Follower.objects.filter(post=post_object, user=user).delete()
            else:
                Follower.objects.create(post=post_object, user=user)
```

Here is Follower model:

```
class Follower(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = FollowerManager()
```

Answer (score 0):

Interactions between a user's browser and the database can only be done via a URL and a view. That view might call a model method, but there is no possible way for the browser to call that method directly.

(Also I don't understand what you're doing in the manager. Why are you deleting followers if the user is authenticated? Note that will always be true, so the followers will always be deleted.)